# Unable to create a table in MySQL 5.1.44

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a website for a client who is an architect who has designed a few good looking buildings in the town. He wants a slider on the home page to showcase his best architecture. I had already integrated the hero slider. It is working fine.

He wants to be able to be able to change the pictures on the slide himself.

So I'm trying to put the slides into a table.

I'm trying to create a table like this in MySQL 5.1.44 but it is NOT taking. It is giving a error number **1064**. Please help -

```
CREATE TABLE slider (
slide_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
building_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
building_loc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in `AUTO INCREMENT` use **[`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)** instead:

```
CREATE TABLE slider ( slide_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                     building_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                     building_loc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92ba8/1/0)**</kbd>